# if function ignores condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm a beginner in Python. I'm curious why does the first if function still prints out even if the number is higher than 0 and why does the calculation still happen if wt=0?

```
wt=float(input("გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ თქვენი წონა (კგ): "))
ht=float(input("გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ თქვენი სიმაღლე (სმ): "))
if wt or ht <= 0:
    print("გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ 0-ზე მაღალი ციფრი")

bmi = wt / (ht * ht)

if bmi < 16:
    print ("თქვენი BMI {:.2f}, რაც ნიშნავს იმას, რომ თქვენ მიეკუთვნებით კატეგორიას, რომლის დასახელებაა - წონის მწვავე დეფიციტი. გესაჭიროებათ მინიმუმ 17 კგ-ის მომატება.  გისურვებთ წარმატებებს!".format(bmi))
```

Comment: because anything other than 0.0 is truthy (your if statement is equivalent to `if wt:` currently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use this code**

```py
wt=float(input("გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ თქვენი წონა (კგ): "))
ht=float(input("გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ თქვენი სიმაღლე (სმ): "))
if wt<=0 or ht <= 0:
    print("გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ 0-ზე მაღალი ციფრი")
    exit()
bmi = wt / (ht * ht)
if bmi < 16:
    print ("თქვენი BMI {:.2f}, რაც ნიშნავს იმას, რომ თქვენ მიეკუთვნებით კატეგორიას, რომლის დასახელებაა - წონის მწვავე დეფიციტი. გესაჭიროებათ მინიმუმ 17 კგ-ის მომატება.  გისურვებთ წარმატებებს!".format(bmi))
```

Comment: This code work.

Comment: this one works only in case if values are higher than 0
but if wt=0, it still goes past if statement and does the calculation of bmi

Comment: Yes, you're right but now it's work.

Comment: What is the `break` for? There's no loop.

Comment: I used exit() instead of sys.exit(), now it works. Thank you!